# Como automatizar a criação de planilhas excel em R

Tags: r

Bom dia,
me encontro em um problema, que apesar de parecer muito simples de resolver, eu não conseguir achar uma solução sem ser fazer manualmente a criação de todos, então vamos lá:

```
library(stringr)
library("xlsx")

lista <- c("L1","L2","L3")
listaData <- c(L1,L2,L3)
##essa linha seria para pegar os dados  l1 l2 l3 do servidor, por isso ocultei, ela esta funcional.
f.pasta <- str_c("C:/Users/.../",lista,".xlsx")
for(idx in (length(listaData))){
idx = 1
write.xlsx( **eu preciso de uma solução para colocar a listaData aqui**, file = fpasta[idx])
}
```

o problema é: quando eu coloco listaData na area em negrito ele ja puxa direto data, se eu tento percorrer o vetor (ex: listaData[1]) ele vai pegar a primeira linha da FUSAO das 3 tabelas (L1L2L3)
como eu tenho que fazer isso 600 vezes, vai se tornar um problema se não automatizar...
espero uma ajuda <3 ty

O que seria uma possivel solução mas eu não sei como fazer:
A listaData ser um TIPO que só chama o nome da variavel L1 e não a tabela de dados. (não sei se é possivel fazer).

Comment: Tente `mapply(write.xlsx, listaData, f.pasta)`. Parece que é só isto, guarda cada tabela de `listaData` em cada ficheiro de `f.pasta`.